# Android get install location with packagename

Tags: android, list, installation, package

Hi i used the following code from this tutorial to list all of the installed applications in an app i'm working on.

http://impressive-artworx.de/2011/list-all-installed-apps-in-style/

I changed the onClick to my own dialog and what i now need to do is be able to get the location of the app. That is if it's in /system/app or /data/app i'd like to be able to toast the entire path to the pressed app but can't figure out how to do this. I can get the packagename by doing app.getPackageName() in the onClick but how can i get the apks path with this? Thank you for any suggestions or help it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more googling i got what i was looking for

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
String s = getPackageName();
PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
s = p.applicationInfo.sourceDir;
```

worked very well found it here

[Get Application Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527764/get-application-directory)

thanks for the help it helped with my googling as to what to look for

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507960/does-android-keep-the-apk-files-if-so-where) . In particular the snippet with [publicSourceDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#publicSourceDir) .

Comment: looks interesting although can't really figure out how to use it do you or anyone else have any experience with this

Answer (score 1):

```
      List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0); //PackageManager.GET_META_DATA 
      for(int i=0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
         PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
         ApplicationInfo a = p.applicationInfo; 
         // skip system apps if they shall not be included
         if ((!includeSysApps) && ((a.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)) {
            continue;
         }
         App app = new App();
         app.setTitle(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
         app.setPackageName(p.packageName);
         app.setVersionName(p.versionName);
         app.setVersionCode(p.versionCode);
         CharSequence description = p.applicationInfo.loadDescription(packageManager);
         app.setDescription(description != null ? description.toString() : "");
         apps.add(app);
      }
```

u can use this code to get the information of installed Applications.