# Get application install location (system or sdcard)

Tags: android, installation, package

Is it possible to check info about the **android:installLocation** of my app, if it is installed on `/data/app` or on SD card?
I need to check if my app moved to SD card then need notify user that the autostart doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Application Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527764/get-application-directory)

Comment: @runDOSrun no it's not duplicate by your link, its duplicate by this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6260246/4387074 , sorry

Answer (score 0):

I used this answer to get application install directory [How to get app install directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527764/get-application-directory)

Hope it helps

Comment: no, this answer suggest use 'getApplicationInfo().dataDir' but when app moved to sdcard, her data directory anyway set on /data/data/appname/

Comment: ok, question can be closed, the ApplicationInfo has parameter .sourceDir that show installed apk directory