# Export apk from phone?

Tags: android, export, apk

I compiled and ran a project on my phone through eclipse which is still install there currently. While doing some directory cleaning I accidentally deleted the source code so the only remaining version of the code is in the apk installed on my phone. Is there anyway to export the app back to my computer?? It isn't signed or anything either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set up to be able to copy files on/off your phone via the USB connection - heres where you can look to find it:
[Does Android keep the .apk files? if so where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507960/does-android-keep-the-apk-files-if-so-where)

Then after you get the .apk off look at these questions for decompiling:

[Is it possible to decompile an Android .apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file)

[decompiling DEX into Java sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode)

Answer (score 1):

You ***CAN*** pull the APK off of the phone, but it's going to be Java Bytecode, not your source code (regardless of whether or not it's signed). You would have to reverse-engineer the classes to retrieve your code. If it's not a VERY large app, I'd say your time would best be spent simply re-creating it.