# Android: app licensing, copy protection

Tags: android, copy-protection, android-lvl

I have an apk file, that is non-free

My questions is the following:

1, If Copy Protection is set to "true" on the market, the users can copy my apk file from the device or not? (rooted/non rooted) [copy apk from device](http://www.jayceooi.com/2010/10/19/how-to-copy-backup-android-apk-file/)

2, If they can: what is the best way to make a REAL copy protection?

Thanks, Leslie

Comment: Copy protection will be deprecated soon, consider using [LVL](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html)

Answer (score 35):

**1.**
**Yes they can**, in rooted phones: http://theandroidsite.com/2009/11/22/how-to-backup-protected-and-paid-android-applications-for-root-users/

APKs are probably stored in /data/app: [Does Android keep the .apk files? if so where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507960/does-android-keep-the-apk-files-if-so-where)
Access at least via Java code or `adb shell` terminal from PC.

**2.**
yorkw already suggested using [LVL](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html).
I'm afraid you cannot make 100% bullet-proof copy-protection and thus shouldn't put your energy into that:

- Any user with a rooted phone can copy your APK and study it.
- With tools like [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and [jd-gui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) one can see all source code in your APKs.
- [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file)
- Most of the identifiers/names in the decompiled source code are scrambled (a,b,c...) but any solid programmer can figure out what your app does.
- Any dishonest party can copy-paste code from jd-gui to an Eclipse project, build, upload into one's Google Account, and put a price tag... smaller than yours.

My advice is to concentrate on building so good apps that no one can keep up with the pace of your innovation and development.

Comment: Thanks I was searching for this answer. specially the last line ;)