# ActionScript 3 FlashDevelop and Air app publishing - xml manifest settings / package issues

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

I'm fairly new to publishing apps with FlashDevelop(FD) and Air, and me and my colleague are having some issues with some settings before the publication of the app.

So, here's the main question, what do you need to do to get a decent setting in package of the manifest-part of the application.xml that gets "merged" with the .apk file?
Is the package i use in my FD project somehow corresponding to the package in  ?
And am I correct in assuming that the package="some.package" also has something to do with where the App actually gets installed on the mobile device?

I mean if I'm writing a very very simple app that is contained in only say 100 lines of code in a single Main class, then i won't be using any package in the FD project... so where does the manifest package get it's string value from?

Been searching on the web for a while now and it's starting to become a wee bit annoying... it's a bit of a jungle and it's hard to find specific answers neither through android's web and adobe air's web.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, no, the package name in your Flash has nothing to do with your apk's package name.

That is set in the settings when you click on 
File->Air for Android Settings

In that dialog under General there's an App ID field which starts with air.
it then says you should fill that in with whatever package name you wish the app to have.

it will wind up being air.your.package.name

And as for reference, you're right, there's not a whole lot on the web, but this book is quite handy:
http://books.google.com/books/about/Developing_Android_Applications_With_Fle.html?id=KGmmyBns0ngC

Or if you're going with straight Flash:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013884.do

Comment: Thanks that solves the main issue (although I was mainly interested in this setting in FlashDevelop not Flash Pro, but turns out it's easy to find the same setting in FD).
However i'd also be interested to know if the package some how effects the install location on the mobile device  :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why that would matter. Android installs stuff wherever it installs stuff.  This question deals with this (sort of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507960/does-android-keep-the-apk-files-if-so-where but I'm not sure why you think this is important. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Hoping to achieve two things, first the obvious - a bit more extended knowledge of the internal workings :-)   and secondly also why I got the error msg "An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed." when the only id/package that would exist is air.appName (since we didn't use any package), if it didn't install in the same folder as some already existing app that also had 'no' package...

Comment: oh, well I'm surprised it lets you compile without specifying a package name. Native Android certainly will not.  Yes, packages have to be unique, so, if you are trying to install an app without a package name or one that is identical to the native air installation (which actually would surprise me, but who knows *how Adobe sets their stuff up) it will certainly be a problem.

Comment: however as we think about it, it's probably due to the fact that my colleague debugged the application on the mobile unit earlier and after that at 'publish' time used a newly created certificate  :-)   developing moves on a winding road  :-)

Comment: well I assume there would be a base package name of air.appName if none was filled out. Seems like it at least :-)