# Where is my APK stored when i run program on a android device?

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

When i just run my program through eclipse on my device it gets installed (since i can open it again from my apps browser). However i cannot find the `.APK` anywhere. Is there a way to pre determine where my `.APK` goes? Otherwise how can i find the folder of an app from the app browser (using `galaxy s4`)?

I have tried searching for files using the ES file explorer app without results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Eclipse, it will be under the `/bin` folder.
In your device, your app will be in `/data/app` folder.

[Does Android keep the .apk files? if so where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507960/does-android-keep-the-apk-files-if-so-where)

Try this code in your app:

```
public class Testing extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "TEST";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        File appsDir = new File("/data/app");

        String[] files = appsDir.list();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < files.length ; i++ ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File: "+files[i]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: @MennoGouw the folder is a protected folder. You wont see the content.

Comment: Cannot get this to run, it does not recognize "Bundle" and "Activity" and i cannot import this either. The post you linked to is more then 4 years old.

Comment: @MennoGouw Basics of the OS are not going to change. I do not know why you cannot import. Have you installed the SDK properly?

Comment: Using LibGDX i do not have direct access to the android sdk.

Comment: I havent used LibGDX so I cannot comment. :/

Comment: Well it is probably possible to add direct access to the android SDK but i'm afraid of breaking things again. I just find it weird that there is an app on my phone and i have no way to locate it. It would help if google made android more transparent.

Comment: @MennoGouw add the given code to your Android project.  You can use Android code in the Android backend for any Libgdx project.  Android does not, by default, let users see much of the content on the device, so Little Child is likely still completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Its in `/bin/` directory in your project path

Comment: Yeah but where is it on my device? Since i can run at when detached from computer and restarted it should be somewhere on my device...

Comment: @MennoGouw Android system installs APK files into `/data/app` directory, but you can't browse this directory, you need a rooted device to list files under.

Comment: Then why is mine not there? I run it from eclipse, no publishing just running using my connected phone as the device.

Comment: Where it should be as stated by you. /data/app/

Comment: when you run the apk from eclipse, the adt compiles the classes into apk file, and store it on your computer into /bin directory in your project path.

Comment: but the mobile device install it to `/data/app` and this directory is not accessible since its protected directory, you need a rooted device to show the list of content of this directory!!

Comment: That is great, now to the question. Where does my device store it when i run it trough Eclipse. Since i can still run it after i disconnected my device and restarted. Even when i am out of range of my wifi network and disabled mobile data.

Comment: :\ I've told you, its in /data/app and you can't read the directory from your computer or your phone file explorer apps...

Answer (score -1):

It is in your bin folder bin/appname.apk

Comment: No it is not... or talking about my PC as well?