# How do I find where an Android app is stored?

Tags: android, user-interface

I see that some of my apps store their files in /Android/data and one of my apps stores its junk right in the root directory of the internal storage. Is there a way to make my phone show me all the places that a particular app stores files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462916/where-is-my-apk-stored-when-i-run-program-on-a-android-device

Comment: I'm not asking where the APK is stored. I understand that an APK is an installer/archive, that is not copied directly to the device and that some of the installed files will be hidden without root access. My question is not a duplicate of the one you linked to. I have rephrased my question to make it more simple for you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

"file explorer" app has to have root access (like "Root Explorer") to view contents of the "data" folder.