# How to get access to application classes.dex file

Tags: android, class, android-layout

I believe that every application can get access to its own files, for example - to classes.dex file.
I wonder how the application get access to its files?

and another question, can I fake this access and get access to another application.?

Comment: you want access to my application? no, no way... i don't agree

Comment: Very funny... c(-: i wanted to create hash of any classes.dex on my device.

Comment: hash? what do you mean?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2508110/1841194) might help you out. After you've found an access to APKs, you need to extract them by a [zip library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324933/what-is-a-good-java-library-to-zip-unzip-files) and then pick their `.dex` files

Comment: I know how to work with Zipfiles and how to get the dex file, and generate an hash of his binary code - to create a digital signature of the file.. but how can I can the access to /data/app ? I dont want an application for rooted device only.

Answer (score 2):

you can point to the apk file of your application using `ApplicationInfo.publicSourceDir`

```
 File yourApk = new File(this.getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir);
 //create the destination dir
 File tempDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "temp_dir");
 //and then unzip the apk to that dir
 unzip(yourApk , tempDir);
 //now the tempDir will contain all the resources including the dex file and its accessible
```

this file is a zip file you can decompress that file using this link

[How to unzip files programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android)

so you will have the access to all resources plus the `classes.dex`

hope this will help

Comment: I know how to work with Zipfiles and how to get the dex file, and generate an hash of his binary code - to create a digital signature of the file.. but how can I can the access to /data/app ? I dont want an application for rooted device only.

Comment: you need to extract the apk(which is a zipped file) and store the content in a local directory so you can access the .dex file
File yourApk = new File(this.getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir);
//now create the destination dir
File tempDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "temp_dir");
//and then unzip the apk to that dir
unzip(yourApk , tempDir);