# Is it possible to transfer an app from one device to another?

Tags: android

Apps like Xender, allow a user to share an app with another user, by directly transferring (and installing the app) on another users device. This is done device to device, and done without the target device downloading the app from google play.

I already know how to transfer a file from one device to another using wifi direct.

My question is - what file do you need to transfer, to transfer the app? Is it the apk ? Where is it located ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the APK of your installed app in `/data/app` in your internal storage . 
Not in every case but most of the time when your are sending an APK you are sending the complete APP .

Also check this post maybe thats what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11908293/7704356

Comment: Thanks! Is there an api to programmatically determine where the apk's are ? Since different phone manufactures can choose to store them in different places...