# Service registration during APK installation

Tags: android, android-intent, service, apk

Lately I've been messing around with Android internals. To better understand the way APKs are installed, I decided to make a testing APK and install it manually with the help of root ADB shell:

- I create an application directory `/data/app/com.example.myapp-y6zjC4JYhJKOph-sl-G5QA==` and copy the APK there (as `base.apk`). The directory suffix is copied from "proper" installation on another device, even though I think it might be anything, since it is a base64 encoded [random string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50895776/6136143).
- I create directory `/data/data/com.example.myapp` and its subdirectories `cache` and `code_cache`
- I modify `packages.xml` and `packages.list` and into each of them I add an entry about my application (again, copied from another "proper" installation).

After I reboot the device, I can verify that the application is installed using `adb shell pm list packages | grep myapp`, which finds my package. I can successfully run the application using `adb shell am start -n com.example.myapp/.MainActivity`.

However, when I wanted to implement a service in my application (started automatically from `MainActivity.onStart`), the service does not start and prints an error message into the log:

```
ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.myapp/.MyService } U=0: not found
```

The service is not displayed in `dumpsys` either:

```
# adb shell dumpsys activity service com.example.myapp
No services match: com.example.myapp
```

The way I call `startService` is the following:

```java
Log.e("MYAPP", "About to start the service"); // This is printed to the log
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

I have tried to change `getApplicationContext()` for `this` in the `Intent` argument, but it didn't help. The service is properly registered in AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<application ... >
 ...
    <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.example.myapp.MyService" android:enabled="true"></service>
</application>
```

Again, I have tried altering a few things in the Manifest: changing `com.example.myapp.MyService` for `.MyService`, removing the `enabled` flag and using one line tag (ending with `/>`) instead of `<service>...</service>`. None of those helped.

**My questions are:**

- Why does the system not see my service?
- Is there any way the services are "registered" during APK installation? Do I need to modify some other configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I discovered a solution a day after I asked the question.

If you ever encounter such a problem, for some reason you need to start the service like this:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
intent.setClassName("com.example.myapp", "com.example.myapp.MyService"); // add this line
startService(intent);
```

I don't know why this happens, the intent seems to be identical. When I print `intent.toString()` to the log before and after I call `intent.setClassName`, both lines look like this:

```
Intent { cmp=com.example.myapp/.MyService }
```

If anyone knows the reason for this behavior, please share it with me, as I have no idea why this happens.